# onclick add 1 to counter + store to server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, button, onclick

i was looking to use a counter on my site so when anyone clicks certain buttons it adds +1 to the counter. I want it so that when you refresh the page the number stays the same, and when a different user clicks the button then it just adds +1 to the counter.

Is this possible? I'm fairly new to Javascript & Jquery so if you could explain it all out it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post what you have tried.

Comment: This is not something you will likely want to do with JS and/or jQuery alone. Are you using a backend technology to connect this with a database or flat file?

Comment: Im willing to do whatever really databases, whatever. Could anyone give me a code for this please?

Answer (score 2):

### Using AJAX and PHP to communicate with a file on the server:

(save this code in a file as `index.php` and you're good to go!)

There might be an easier way to do it, but I'll show you how to do it using **AJAX** (n**o page refresh**) and **PHP** that will allow you to do whatever you want with that counter value in JS.

The provided PHP is not the most secure in the world, but might be secure enough for your needs.
It will create automatically a file called `counter.txt` if there's none on your server folder (same path as index.php file).

By clicking any of the `button` elements (it's up tu you to change the jQuery selector) the AJAX get will read from the file the current value stored in your file and will than send an incremented counter value.

```
<?php
$file = 'counter.txt';
// CREATE FILE
if(!file_exists($file)){
    $create = fopen($file, 'w') or die("Could not create the counter database.");
    file_put_contents( $file , '0' );
    fclose($create);
}
// WRITE FILE
if( isset($_POST['count']) ){
    $msg = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['count']), ENT_QUOTES);
    file_put_contents($file, $msg);
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Flat-File db counter with PHP and AJAX by roXon</title>
</head>
<body>

<button>click me</button> 
<button>click me too!</button> 
refresh the page , the counter should be memorized from our auto-generated database file! ;)
<br><b></b>

<script>
    function addCount( newCounterValue ){
        $.ajax( {
            type: "POST",
            data: {count : newCounterValue},
            cache: false,
                    async: false,
            success: function() {
                $('b').append('<br>Succesfully sent: '+ newCounterValue);
            }
        });
    }
    $(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){       
            $.get('counter.txt', function(data) {
                // READ
                var counter = parseInt(data, 10) || 0;
                $('b').html('Retrieved counter from database = '+ data);
                // SEND
                addCount( ++counter ); // send preIncremented COUNTER
            });     
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

A client-side solution (**will not be available to other users!**) would be using HTML5 `localStorage`

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/axeyaq/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
var counter = localStorage.getItem('counter') || 0;

$('button').click(function(){
     localStorage.setItem('counter', ++counter);
     alert(counter);
});
```

**NOTE** this is client side only. You can take a look at PHP how to create a file on the fly and send that value into that file.
On click I'd suggest you to use AJAX to contact that file and read the current value before updating it with PHP.

Comment: I'm confused, how would I put this into my index?

Comment: @user1952279 if you want I can show you how to use flat-file database in PHP ... if that's fine for your needs

Comment: @user1952279 done. This code will automatically create a `counter.txt` on your server and store the initial value '0' :)

Comment: Thanks for this great help! Just one more thing.. In a separate file I want the amount of time it's been clicked showed, how can i do this?

Comment: @user1952279 simply use the `$.get` method like I did to **read** the value (just modify it for your needs) If you don't know how to do it, you can hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: What is this line doing?  `var counter = localStorage.getItem('counter') || 0;` or more specifically, the `|| 0;`?  Thanks.

Comment: @dlackey the `OR || operator` does: if nothing is returned by localstorage (nothing was set before) than add valu `0` to `counter`. in other words, if the first one returns false, null, undefined... set value to '0'